# Webpack img-loader can not load image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am tring to load image locally, the image file is in the same folder of jsx file. The webpack.config.js is looks like this:

```
path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./app/entry.jsx,
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[resourcePath]',
    devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[resourcePath]?[hash]'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader?root=."
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000!img?progressive=true'
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx" ]
  }
};
```

and the jsx is like this

```
var loadingImg = require('url!img!./loading.gif');
```

the error shows in console is:

```
ERROR in Loader app/node_modules/url/url.js didn't return a function
 @ app/components/session/login.jsx 5:17-49
```

How should I load this image?

Comment: You don't need the loaders defined in the `require()`. From the docs: "[Specifying loaders in the configuration is the recommended approach](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html)"

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is jumping out at me as incorrect in your webpack config file. I would take a look at the way you're calling the image in your code, doesn't look right to me. I'm not sure where you're trying to use the code, but you could do something like;

```
<img src={require("../../images/some-filepath/some-image.png")} />
```

or:

```
<Image source={{uri: '../../images/some-filepath/some-image.png'}} />
```

I did make a [tutorial a while ago](http://davidmeents.com/how-to-set-up-webpack-image-loader/) for using the image-webpack-loader, if you want to take a look.

Anyway, hope this helps!